# unset a function for one line in a bash script

Tags: bash

In a script, I've defined: `rm() { echo "rm $@" }`

Normally `rm` would run `echo rm`, but I want to change it for a single line to run the actual `rm` command. How can I do this?

I've tried:

`rm= rm file` but this still runs `echo rm file`

I don't want to `unset rm` because I still want to be able to run `rm file` and expect it to echo.

Note: `rm` is just an example command, not the command I'm actually using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `command` to run a command instead of a function by the same name:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname() {
  echo "You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike. "
}

hostname            # runs the function
command hostname    # runs the external command
```

Comment: This answer is best, but an alternative is to use the full path `/bin/rm`.